# Link a sharepoint with an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets. I'm trying to create a sharepoint list for each sheet and when the excel spreadsheet is updated, the sharepoint is updated.

It looks like you can link an access database with sharepoint but I'm struggling to find a guide to link a sharepoint with an excel.

Comment: I gooogled "link a sharepoint with an excel", and this link came up https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-list-with-a-spreadsheet-program-d4337a01-2be4-43b5-bb42-28aefe64eafd

Comment: Yup, I read that too. You can link an excel document with a sharepoint list, so updating the sharepoint will update the spreadsheet. I'm trying to do the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it isn't possible to modify a spreadsheet and have it update SharePoint, you can only update the spreadsheet with changes from SharePoint.

From reading the MS documentation found at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-list-with-a-spreadsheet-program-d4337a01-2be4-43b5-bb42-28aefe64eafd

> There are three ways to synchronize data between a SharePoint list and
>   a spreadsheet program. Whichever way you choose, this synchronization
>   is one-way, or unidirectional. Changes made in the SharePoint list can
>   be updated in the spreadsheet program, **but any changes that you make
>   in the spreadsheet program are not written to the SharePoint list**.

It seems that the best you can do is to update SharePoint by creating a new list, but that probably isn't going to help you unless you can somehow use the new list to replace the old one.

As you state, you can do a bi-directional synch from Access, and this is confirmed by the MS documentation https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-2010-list-with-Access-2010-975BFB97-C799-4FCE-B7CC-3DB3B397F116

> There are three ways to synchronize data between a SharePoint list and
>   Access 2010. **Whichever way you choose, this synchronization is
>   two-way, or bi-directional**.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with MS Flow, though it requires a bit of effort. You can then trigger the flow based off any conditions you want (Excel doc saved, once a day, etc)

Instructions can be found here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-Sharepoint-List-From-Excel-File/td-p/111477